# In 这个跟那个不(是)一样 and 我们不(是)一样, is 是 totally redundant?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence-structure

1. 这个跟那个不一样。   From a native online teacher.
2. 这个跟那个不是一样。  If I formed it myself.
3. 我们不是一样。  If I formed it myself.
4. 我们不一样。  If I followed the similarity of 1 above.

I know the first one got to be correct.  what about the rest?

Edited: I just happened to use the negative  不 in those sentences.  But my question also applied to without the 不.

Answer (score 1):

'不一样' (is not the same) is a set phrase, functions the same as '是不一样的' therefore 是 is redundant in '不是一样'

Either '这个跟那个不一样' or '这个跟那个是不一样的', but not '这个跟那个不是一样'

Answer (score 0):

In Chinese, an adjective can be used as predicate, and does not have to be accompanied by the Be verbs (am/is/are) or similar verbs (become/turn/...).

For example,

她(She)很(very)漂亮(beautiful), "is" is omitted after "she".

花儿(Flowers)红了(red), "turned" is omitted after "flowers".

我们(We)不(not)一样(the same), "are" is omitted after "we".